# "mount" a file from a foriegn filesystem to a local file system?

Tags: linux, ssh, mount

I have credentials to server which I can SSH into and access the file system on that machine. Within that file system is a file that I need to access continually to see what has been added; a log file. I would like to I guess so to say "mount" that file on my local system so I can open and use it as if it were on my local file system.

My goal is to write a parser for this file that will pull out relevant information as it is added as fast as possible. But currently there is no way for me to open the file within my program because of its location.

I hope that made sense, any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use SSHFS, and mount it with fuse.

```
sshfs user@remote_host:/path/to/directory <local_mount_point>
```

you can configure it in your fstab:

```
sshfs#user@remote_host:/path/to/directory <local_mount_point> fuse user 0 0
```

see more info here: http://xmodulo.com/2013/04/how-to-mount-remote-directory-over-ssh-on-linux.html